# Runge-Kutta Numerical Method Bad Approximation

Tags: matlab, octave, numerical-methods, ode, runge-kutta

I´m attempting to use the Runge-Kutta method to compare it to the lsode function. But it is performing rather poorly, every other method I used (forwards and backwards Euler, Heun) to compare to lsode do a way better job to the point they are almost indistinguishable from lsode.

This is what my code returns
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ6Yi.png

If anyone can point out a way to improve it or if I'm doing something wrong I´d appreciate it.

The following is what I use for the Runge-Kutta method

```
%Initial conditions

u(1) = 1;
v(1) = 2;
p(1) = -1/sqrt(3);
q(1) = 1/sqrt(3);

%Graf interval / step size
s0 = 0;
sf = 50;
h = 0.25;

n=(sf-s0)/h;

s(1) = s0;

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------% 

for j = 2:n

  i = j-1;

  k1_u(j) = p(i);
  k1_v(j) = q(i);
  k1_p(j) = (-2*v(i)*p(i)*q(i)) / (u(i)*u(i) + v(i)*v(i) + 1);
  k1_q(j) = (-2*u(i)*p(i)*q(i)) / (u(i)*u(i) + v(i)*v(i) + 1);

  u1(j) = p(i) + (1/2)*k1_u(j)*h;
  v1(j) = q(i) + (1/2)*k1_v(j)*h;
  p1(j) = (-2*v(i)*p(i)*q(i)) / (u(i)*u(i) + v(i)*v(i) + 1) + (1/2)*k1_p(j)*h;
  q1(j) = (-2*u(i)*p(i)*q(i)) / (u(i)*u(i) + v(i)*v(i) + 1) + (1/2)*k1_q(j)*h;

  k2_u(j) = p1(j);
  k2_v(j) = q1(j);
  k2_p(j) = (-2*v1(j)*p1(j)*q1(j)) / (u1(j)*u1(j) + v1(j)*v1(j) + 1);
  k2_q(j) = (-2*u1(j)*p1(j)*q1(j)) / (u1(j)*u1(j) + v1(j)*v1(j) + 1);

  u2(j) = p(i) + (1/2)*k2_u(j)*h;
  v2(j) = q(i) + (1/2)*k2_v(j)*h;
  p2(j) = (-2*v(i)*p(i)*q(i)) / (u(i)*u(i) + v(i)*v(i) + 1) + (1/2)*k2_p(j)*h;
  q2(j) = (-2*u(i)*p(i)*q(i)) / (u(i)*u(i) + v(i)*v(i) + 1) + (1/2)*k2_q(j)*h;

  k3_u(j) = p2(j);
  k3_v(j) = q2(j);
  k3_p(j) = (-2*v2(j)*p2(j)*q2(j)) / (u2(j)*u2(j) + v2(j)*v2(j) + 1);
  k3_q(j) = (-2*u2(j)*p2(j)*q2(j)) / (u2(j)*u2(j) + v2(j)*v2(j) + 1);

  u3(j) = p(i) + k3_u(j)*h;
  v3(j) = q(i) + k3_v(j)*h;
  p3(j) = (-2*v(i)*p(i)*q(i)) / (u(i)*u(i) + v(i)*v(i) + 1) + k3_p(j)*h;
  q3(j) = (-2*u(i)*p(i)*q(i)) / (u(i)*u(i) + v(i)*v(i) + 1) + k3_q(j)*h;

  k4_u(j) = p3(j);
  k4_v(j) = q3(j);
  k4_p(j) = (-2*v3(j)*p3(j)*q3(j)) / (u3(j)*u3(j) + v3(j)*v3(j) + 1);
  k4_q(j) = (-2*u3(j)*p3(j)*q3(j)) / (u3(j)*u3(j) + v3(j)*v3(j) + 1);


    s(j) = s(j-1) + h;
    u(j) = u(j-1) + (h/6)*(k1_u(j) + 2*k2_u(j) + 2*k3_u(j) + k4_u(j));
    v(j) = v(j-1) + (h/6)*(k1_v(j) + 2*k2_v(j) + 2*k3_v(j) + k4_v(j));
    p(j) = p(j-1) + (h/6)*(k1_p(j) + 2*k2_p(j) + 2*k3_p(j) + k4_p(j));
    q(j) = q(j-1) + (h/6)*(k1_q(j) + 2*k2_q(j) + 2*k3_q(j) + k4_q(j));

endfor

subplot(2,3,1), plot(s,u);
hold on; plot(s,v); hold off;

title ("Runge-Kutta");
h = legend ("u(s)", "v(s)");
legend (h, "location", "northwestoutside");
set (h, "fontsize", 10);
```

Comment: I'd write `u(i).^2` rather then `u(i)*u(i)`. Makes your code a bit more readable :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will change it in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood something in the method. The intermediate values for `p,q` are computed the same way as the intermediate values for `u,v`, and both are "Euler steps" with the last computed slopes, not separate slope computations. For the first ones that is

```
  u1(j) = u(i) + (1/2)*k1_u(j)*h;
  v1(j) = v(i) + (1/2)*k1_v(j)*h;
  p1(j) = p(i) + (1/2)*k1_p(j)*h;
  q1(j) = q(i) + (1/2)*k1_q(j)*h;
```

The computation for the `k2` values then is correct, the next midpoints need to be computed correctly via "Euler steps", etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it. :)

Comment: Then please mark the question as answered @R.FALLEN